# How to convert xml to graphviz using saxonica

Tags: xml, xslt, graphviz, dot

I have an xml code as shown below, The xml contains several elements, namely: id, parent menu, label, role id, role and items. in items there is 1 element, namely submenu, and in submenu there are 2 elements, namely url and label:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "policy.xsl" ?>
<Import>
    <Row>
        <id>1</id>
        <parentmenu>siasn-instansi</parentmenu>
        <label>Layanan Profile ASN</label>
        <role_id>1</role_id>
        <role>role:siasn-instansi:profilasn:viewprofil</role>
        <items>
            <subMenu name = "pns">
                 <url>/tampilanData/pns</url>
                 <label>Profile Pegawai</label>
            </subMenu>
            <subMenu name = "pppk">
                 <url>/tampilanData/pppk</url>
                 <label>Profile Pegawai PPPK</label>
            </subMenu>
            <subMenu name = "ppt">
                 <url>/tampilanData/JPTNonASN</url>
                 <label>Profile Pegawai PPT Non-ASN</label>
            </subMenu>
        </items>
    </Row>
</Import>
```

and the code below is the code for the xslt, using XSL language with dotML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML" version="3.0">
    <xsl:import href="http://www.martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/dotml2dot.xsl"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="dotml">
          <xsl:for-each select = "Import/Row">
            <graph file-name="graphs/node">
                <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select='role'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select='role'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </node>   
                <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </node>   
                <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pppk"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pppk"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </node>   
                <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="ppt"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="ppt"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </node>  

                <edge fontname="Arial" fontsize="9" label="Permit">
                    <xsl:attribute name="from">
                        <xsl:value-of select='role'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="to">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </edge>   
                <edge fontname="Arial" fontsize="9" label="Permit">
                    <xsl:attribute name="from">
                        <xsl:value-of select='role'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="to">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pppk"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </edge>   
                <edge fontname="Arial" fontsize="9" label="Permit">
                    <xsl:attribute name="from">
                        <xsl:value-of select='role'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="to">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="ppt"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </edge>   
            </graph>
          </xsl:for-each>         
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$dotml/node()"/>
      
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xsl above is the xslt of my xml document. and I want to convert it so that it can be run on graphviz. I have corrected the above code according to @martin Honnen's suggestion, by adding the code:

```
<xsl:import href="http://www.martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/dotml2dot.xsl"/>
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$dotml/node()"/>
```

and have successfully changed from dotML code to graphviz code, like the code below:

```
    digraph g {
    compound="true";bgcolor="";fontcolor="";fontname="";fontsize="";label="";margin="";nodesep="";rankdir="";ranksep="";ratio="";size="";
    node[label="role:siasn-instansi:profilasn:viewprofil", color="",fillcolor="",fixedsize="",fontcolor="",fontname="",fontsize="16",height="",shape="",style="filled",URL="",width="",] 
         {role:siasn-instansi:profilasn:viewprofil};
         node[label="/tampilanData/pns", color="",fillcolor="",fixedsize="",fontcolor="",fontname="",fontsize="16",height="",shape="",style="filled",URL="",width="",] 
         {/tampilanData/pns};
         node[label="/tampilanData/pppk", color="",fillcolor="",fixedsize="",fontcolor="",fontname="",fontsize="16",height="",shape="",style="filled",URL="",width="",] 
         {/tampilanData/pppk};
         node[label="/tampilanData/JPTNonASN", color="",fillcolor="",fixedsize="",fontcolor="",fontname="",fontsize="16",height="",shape="",style="filled",URL="",width="",] 
        {/tampilanData/JPTNonASN};
        edge[arrowhead="",arrowsize="",arrowtail="",constraint="",color="",decorate="",dir="",fontcolor="",fontname="Arial",fontsize="9",headlabel="",headport="",label="Permit",labeldistance="",labelfloat="",labelfontcolor="",labelfontname="",labelfontsize="",minlen="",samehead="",sametail="",style="",taillabel="",tailport="",URL="",lhead="",ltail=""]
         role:siasn-instansi:profilasn:viewprofil -> /tampilanData/pns;edge[arrowhead="",arrowsize="",arrowtail="",constraint="",color="",decorate="",dir="",fontcolor="",fontname="Arial",fontsize="9",headlabel="",headport="",label="Permit",labeldistance="",labelfloat="",labelfontcolor="",labelfontname="",labelfontsize="",minlen="",samehead="",sametail="",style="",taillabel="",tailport="",URL="",lhead="",ltail=""] 
         role:siasn-instansi:profilasn:viewprofil -> /tampilanData/pppk;edge[arrowhead="",arrowsize="",arrowtail="",constraint="",color="",decorate="",dir="",fontcolor="",fontname="Arial",fontsize="9",headlabel="",headport="",label="Permit",labeldistance="",labelfloat="",labelfontcolor="",labelfontname="",labelfontsize="",minlen="",samehead="",sametail="",style="",taillabel="",tailport="",URL="",lhead="",ltail=""] 
         role:siasn-instansi:profilasn:viewprofil -> /tampilanData/JPTNonASN;
    }
<dot-filename>graphs/node</dot-filename>
```

the code above is the result of the conversion that I did using saxonica like the code below:

java -jar saxon-he-10.6.jar role-policy.xml role-policy.xsl -o:policy.txt

I want to know how the contents of the code that I have converted from xml using an xsl document that I made into a txt form with the help of saxonica like the code above.

then the last step according to my goal, I immediately converted my xml file into a dot file, using saxonica as well as the code below:

```
C:\Users\rafif\Desktop\saxons>dot -Tpng policy.dot -o policy_dot.png
Error: policy.dot: syntax error in line 1 near '-'
```

but unfortunately it's still an error.

the problem is only in the "double-quotes" in each of the fetched values in my xml document.

and the second problem when converting using saxon, there is still a `<dot-filename>graphs/node</dot-filename>` tag,

- the question is, how to get this tag: `<xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url'/>` and `<xsl:value-of select='role'/>` tag in my xsl document , when converted to a dot file using saxon the result becomes a string (there are double-quotes) in the value.
- and how to remove the `<dot-filename>graphs/node</dot-filename>` tag?

so I don't need to convert it to a txt file first, add "double-quotes" to each value, and remove the `<dot-filename>graphs/node</dot-filename>` tag, so the file can be directly converted to dot . no need to convert to txt first

thank you

Comment: As Martin says, you need to convert the dotML to dot syntax. Note also that your code does not need to be so verbose, for example lines 6..13 can be replaced with `<node style="filled" fontsize="16" id="{role}" label="{role}" />`. (Look up "attribute value templates").

Comment: michael thank you for your response, can you see my question above, because my question has been updated, can you help me? thanks

Comment: This is not an answer, it is just some notes: The output you show in your question is not a valid DOT file. To convert it into something valid you can take these steps: (1) Remove the lines containing `{ ... };` (if those are part of DOT syntax, I am not familiar with them). (2) Ensure your edge labels are all contained in double-quotes - so, from `abc -> def` to "abc" -> "def"`. If you make these changes, then you will be able to generate a valid PNG file. Will it be the PNG you actually want? I have no idea. How do you change your XML processing code to achieve this? I have no idea.

Comment: i did it.... i love you andrewwww..... !!!!

Comment: @andrewJames can you see my question above, because my question has been updated, can you help me? thanks, you're right, the problem is about the "double quotes".

Answer (score 0):

I think your code does try to generate DotML (though with the wrong namespace), the creator of that language has a stylesheet you can import to generate Dot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML" version="3.0">
    <xsl:import href="http://www.martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/dotml2dot.xsl"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="dotml">
          <xsl:for-each select = "Import/Row">
            <graph file-name="graphs/node">
                <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select='role'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select='role'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </node>   
                <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </node>   
                <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pppk"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pppk"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </node>   
                <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="ppt"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="ppt"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </node>  

                <edge fontname="Arial" fontsize="9" label="Permit">
                    <xsl:attribute name="from">
                        <xsl:value-of select='role'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="to">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </edge>   
                <edge fontname="Arial" fontsize="9" label="Permit">
                    <xsl:attribute name="from">
                        <xsl:value-of select='role'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="to">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pppk"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </edge>   
                <edge fontname="Arial" fontsize="9" label="Permit">
                    <xsl:attribute name="from">
                        <xsl:value-of select='role'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="to">
                        <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="ppt"]/url'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </edge>   
            </graph>
          </xsl:for-each>         
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$dotml/node()"/>
      
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I haven't tested whether the result can be consumed Graphviz.

Comment: thanks martin for the responds, but what is the $dotml/node() in tag <xsl:apply-templates select="$dotml/node()"/> , should I write exactly like that in the xsl:apply-templates tag?

Comment: @RafifFavian, yes, it is just an attempt to combine your previous stylesheet and its result, stored in the variable `<xsl:variable name="dotml">` to then apply the imported stylesheet from the website that hopefully turns the DotML your code produces into the Dot format your tool can work with.

Comment: thank you for your response, can you see my question above, because my question has been updated, can you help me? thanks

Comment: Try to remove the last line `<dot-filename>graphs/node</dot-filename>` from the result and test whether the file can then be processed.

Comment: it's same..., still error
C:\Users\rafif\Desktop\saxons>dot -Tpng policy.dot -o policy_dot.png                                                                                                                                               Error: policy.dot: syntax error in line 1 near '-'

Comment: @RafifFavian, I neither familiar with DotML nor with the Dot language. So I am afraid I can't help really, I just tried to find a way to make sense in the terms of XML and XSLT. Which parts of these languages do you know, DotML or Dot, or both? Where does the original XSLT come from that tries to create DotML? Has it been authored by someone that knows DotML? I tried to validate the create DotML against the schema http://www.martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/dotml-1.4.xsd, it doesn't seem to create valid DotML to begin with.

Comment: can you see my question above, because my question has been updated, can you help me how to delete the <dot-filename>graphs/node</dot-filename> in my xsl code? thanks,